# Why won't my result update after the first iteration(?)

Tags: c, pointers

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

void scan_data(char *op, float *operand);
float do_next_op(char op, float operand, float *accumulator);

int main(void)
{
    char op;
    float operand;
    float accumulator = 0;

    do
    {
        printf(" + add\n - subtract\n * multiply\n / divide\n ^ power\n q quit\n\n");
        scan_data(&op, &operand);

        if(op == 'q' || op == 'Q')
        {
            printf("Final result is %.1f\n", do_next_op(op, operand, &accumulator));
            break;
        }
        else
        {
           printf("result so far is %.1f\n", do_next_op(op, operand, &accumulator));


        }
    }while(op != 'q' || op == 'Q');


}


void scan_data(char *op, float *operand)
{
    scanf("%c%f",op, operand);
}

float do_next_op(char op, float operand, float *accumulator)
{


    switch(op)
    {
        case('+'):
            *accumulator = *accumulator + operand;
            break;
        case('-'):
            *accumulator = *accumulator - operand;
            break;
        case('*'):
            *accumulator = *accumulator * operand;
            break;
        case('/'):
            *accumulator = *accumulator / operand;
            break;
        case('^'):
            *accumulator = pow(*accumulator,operand);
            break;
    }
    return *accumulator;

}
```

I'm trying to code a "simple" calculator where if i type

+5.0
result so far is 5.0

^2
result so far is 25.0

/ 2.0
result so far is 12.5

Q 0
final result is 12.5

The problem is, the code will "correctly" output the first operation but if i put anymore operation after that I doesn't update to the new value. 
How can I fix the code to do what I intend to do?

I'm sorry in advance if my question wording and format is off, I don't know how to ask it in a proper way.

Comment: Have you attempted to debug the program to try and narrow down the problem? The best way to do that is to run your program in a debugger. For example, have you verified that the variables are as expected, especially `op` and `operand`? [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: Another tip is to always check the return value of all functions. That will make your code more robust and will help you find many problems more easily. In this case, check the `scanf` result and print an error if it is not as expected.

Comment: Since you’ve got a `”%c%f”` format, you’re almost certainly running foul of the `%c` not skipping white space.  Add a blank before the `%c`.  Only three `scanf()` directives don’t skip white space — `%c`, `%[…]` (scan sets), and `%n`.

Comment: If you run your program in a debugger or even just print out the values of `op` and `operand` you will find that `op` contains a newline on the second iteration. Then should lead you to search SO for why `scanf` would put a newline there in that situation.

Comment: Note that `float accumulator = 0;` has only been initialised *once* so move that inside the loop, for the next calculation. Or is it supposed to keep modifying the value? Also, as mentioned, there is a problem with `scanf("%c%f",op, operand);` reading a newline left in the buffer instead of the next operator. Try adding a space as `scanf(" %c%f",op, operand);`

Comment: its supposed to keep modifying the value

Comment: I added more to that comment.

Comment: Tip: `%e` and `%g`  are more informative in displaying large/small FP values than `%.1f`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the problem is in the statement:

```
scanf("%c%f",op, operand);
```

After the first iteration, there is a left over newline in `stdin`

That `newline` is a 'white space', typically `\n`

That 'white space must be consumed before the `%c` rather than the `%c` consuming it.  Suggest:

```
scanf(" %c%f",op, operand);
```

where the leading space in the format string consumes that 'white space'

regarding the statement:

```
*accumulator = pow(*accumulator,operand);
```

the `pow()` function expects to be working with `double` values, not `float` values.  Suggest:

```
*accumulator = powf(*accumulator,operand);
```

Notice this is calling `powf()` not `pow()`